# bit shifting in javascript

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I have an numerical value such as

```
var x = 13434235234334;
```

I want to bit shift it to the left or to the right. E.g.:

```
x >> 2
```

or

```
x << 2
```

but then later in time I want to get back the original value of x (assume that I know how many times I shifted the original number).

How do I get the original value of `x` back?

Comment: The thing about bit shifting is that shifted bits are discarded. If you want the original number then store it in a variable.

Comment: The thing about huge numbers is that bit shifting in Javascript only works on integers. `13434235234334` is initially parsed as a double, but the bit shift converts it to an integer (which subsequently overflows). So this cannot be done the way you envision it. Try printing `x | 0` and you'll see.

Comment: That depends. Shifting drops the number of bits you are shifting it on the side you shift towards and zerofills on the opposing side. If you are lucky and only zeros get dropped (e.g. when you shift to the left on small numbers) then you can recreate the original value by shifting towards the opposite direction by the same amount, but in most cases that won't happen and you cannot regain the original value unless you stored it elsewhere.

Comment: Divide by 4 and use `Math.floor(x)` instead of `x`. Multiplying by 4 returns the original value again. ...But seriously, why not keep a copy?

Answer (score 0):

The original value, `x`, itself is not altered by bit-shifting operations.

```
var x=511;
var y=x>>4;
var z=x<<3;
/*
x=511
y=31
z=4088
*/
```

So just use `x` if you want the original value, as long as you aren't assigning some other value to `x`.

Comment: say that x was altered somehow... how could I get the values back by using only bit-shifting?

Comment: @Draconar Depends on the operation.  In assembler you typically have rotate instructions which I suppose preserves some information which might allow you to reconstruct the original value.  But in languages that don't support rotate, only bit-shifting, well you're very likely going to lose information from bit-shifting and manipulation, making the original value unrecoverable.  Either have a copy of original `x`, or don't tamper with it if you need its value later.

Comment: @Draconar Also if you do want bit-rotation instead of bit-shift then this can be done with `((x<<r) | (x>>>(32-r)))` and/or `((x>>>r) | (x<<(32-r)))` where x is your original value, r is the number of shifts to perform in the rotation, and 32 is obviously the total number of bits (size of the integer).  This preserves the sequence of bits relative to each other in your original data, which can be recovered as long as you keep track of the total shifts.  Is this something you were aiming for?

Comment: @jongo45: look at the original suggested value of `x`. It's *way* out of range for simple bit operations in Javascript -- this needs an entire BigInt implementation written in JS.